# The closure of the subgroup generated by a vector field may not be compact

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology

Suppose $X$ is a vector field on a manifold $M$, consider the one parameter group:
$$L=\left\{\phi^t_X: t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$
where $\phi^t_X$ is the flow of the vector field $X$, which sends $p\in M$ to $\phi^t_X(p)$. Then $L$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$, the closure $\overline{L}$ may not be a compact subgroup. I have difficulty finding an example.

Here is an example, but I cannot verify which is non-compact.

Consider the vector field $X$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$X(p,q)=\left(q(p^2+q^2),-p(p^2+q^2)\right).$$
The flow of $X$ is
$$L=\left\{\phi^t_X:z\mapsto e^{i\lvert z\rvert^2t}\mathrel\vert t\in\mathbb{R} \right\}.$$
Where we setting $(p,q)=z$, the flow is to rotate $z$ along the origin by $\lvert z\rvert^2t$.
How to show this $\overline{L}$ is non-compact?

Comment: Note that compactness of the closure might depend on the topology on $\mathrm{Diff}(X)$ (it is also natural to ask about compactness of the closure in the compact-open topology of $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$).

Comment: This example seems unnecessarily complicated. How about $M=\mathbb R$, $X=1$, so $\phi_t(x)=x+t$ ?

Comment: Note that you need to assume that $X$ is complete. Otherwise $\phi^t_X(x)$ is not even defined for all pairs $(x,t)\in M\times\mathbb R$. In particular, $X$ does not necessarily define a subgroup.